# False class "menu"

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I got the following menu item in my footer, the context is as follows: A WordPress website that's translated to English, in my original site (NL) my footer is fine. However, in my English footer I came upon the following :

[image: False class example]

I have tried to search for just what a false class is or where it comes from, but I can't seem to find anything CSS or javascript related as to why that's there. In fact, I've never heard of any such thing as a false class.

At first, I tried to isolate the class itself by narrowing down where it came from. As I could not find what it was I took to google and stack overflow. Eventually, I found the answer by digging into something another user said.

It's not the most elegant mistake anyone has ever made but I'll leave it here so that the next person who makes the same mistake has a reference.

Perhaps someone here can enlighten me as to where to look for this and what it is. Right now I've just added a CSS rule: ".col-lg-10.false {display:none;}" this works but of course it tells me absolutely nothing about the problem itself.

I'm talking about the website: https://zinderboats.com when you switch into English, and check the source you will be able to find said class by using the inspector on the footer.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to provide links to both websites before anybody can say anything about it.

Comment: That's not a "false class", that's a `<false>` element with a class of `menu`. What's a `<false>` element? No idea.

Comment: i think any typing mistake

Comment: Interesting thing, that in browser: `document.createElement(false)` creates element <false>. This also works with `true, null, undefined, NaN, Infinity`.

Answer (score 2):

@AuxTaco brought me to the idea that I may have missed something (as its not my code), so I went back into the footer.php and found this line :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('items_wrap' => '%3$s','theme_location'=>'footer-menu','container'=>'false') );?>
```

Hidden between the normal menu elements, I have no idea why it's there but I have removed it nothing broke and it works just fine now.